# Using Moment.js to make an array of this week's dates doesn't add to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to make a Resource Calendar and I need an array of dates for this week. The console log of my current function prints out appropriately but the array that gets pushed in for each date is wrong.

```
    var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week');
    var endOfWeek = moment().endOf('week');

    var days = [];
    var day = startOfWeek;

    do {
        console.log(day._d);
        days.push(day._d);
        day = day.add(1, 'd');
    }
    while (day <= endOfWeek);

    console.log(days);
```

Returns:

```
Sun Jan 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) schedule.js?320233fd69f9859ccb55248b608e15891032b17d:31
Mon Jan 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) schedule.js?320233fd69f9859ccb55248b608e15891032b17d:31
Tue Jan 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) schedule.js?320233fd69f9859ccb55248b608e15891032b17d:31
Wed Jan 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) schedule.js?320233fd69f9859ccb55248b608e15891032b17d:31
Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) schedule.js?320233fd69f9859ccb55248b608e15891032b17d:31
Fri Jan 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) schedule.js?320233fd69f9859ccb55248b608e15891032b17d:31
Sat Jan 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) schedule.js?320233fd69f9859ccb55248b608e15891032b17d:31
[Sun Jan 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), Sun Jan 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), Sun Jan 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), Sun Jan 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), Sun Jan 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), Sun Jan 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), Sun Jan 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)]
```

Notice how the array at the bottom is the next date in the array repeated 7 times.

Comment: `day.add()` doesn't return a new moment object ([`.add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)) - it's always the same.

Comment: You are seeing this behavior because you are pushing a reference into the array (`day._d`) and not a copy of its value during the iteration.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As danludwig mentioned in his comment on the question, you are adding a reference for the same date to the array multiple times.

From the [Moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/):

> It should be noted that moments are mutable. Calling any of the manipulation methods will change the original moment.
>
> If you want to create a copy and manipulate it, you should use moment#clone before manipulating the moment.

You should be calling the `clone` function on the Moment date object as shown [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/).

```
var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week');
var endOfWeek = moment().endOf('week');

var days = [];
var day = startOfWeek;

while (day <= endOfWeek) {
    days.push(day.toDate());
    day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
}

console.log(days);
```

As an aside:

You *should not* reference internal fields/functions of a 3rd party library. The name of these references are more likely to change than the public API described in the documentation. `_d` can be referenced by calling the [public function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) `toDate`.

Comment: It's awesome! Thank you Taylor!